# alerts bootstrap coding twig to php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I have coding from someone that make a alerts bootstrap use twig not php, and i would change it to php coding, this is twig coding:

```
            {% for alert in [ 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'error'] %}
            {% if app.session.hasFlash(alert) %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ alert }}">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                {{ app.session.flash(alert) }}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
```

can you help me for change that twig code to php code? 
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple...

```
<?php
    if (in_array($alert, array('info', 'success', 'warning', 'error')) {
        if (isset($_SESSION["flash"][$alert])) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $alert; ?>">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <?php echo $_SESSION["flash"][$alert]; ?>
    </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: The answerer missed the closing bracket `)` on this line: `if (isset($_SESSION["flash"][$alert]) { ?>`. Simply add an extra `)` after `[$alert]`.

Comment: i use codeigniter, and i write code $data['alert'] = array('error', 'info', 'success'); but not show in my view, what's wrong with it ? thank you